"Of countless such cavils does a busy lexicographer’s working day consist"— Why does this inversion use "does"? Can I move "consists" forward instead?
blog.collinsdictionary.com:
(1) Of countless such cavils does a busy lexicographer’s working day consist.
The inversion here has the auxiliary verb "does" although, usually, such an auxiliary appears in an inverted sentence only if this sentence has negation. Since there is no negation in (1), then why is inverting with the auxiliary possible?

my variant:
(2) Of countless such cavils consists a busy lexicographer’s working day.
Is (2) correct?
If not, then why is the inversion in (2) incorrect, whereas the auxiliary-inversion in (1) is correct?

my variant:
(3) Of countless such cavils, a busy lexicographer’s working day consists.
Is (3) correct?

What's the difference between (1), (2) and (3)?

my variant:
(4) A busy lexicographer’s working day consists of countless such cavils. — I understand this variant is correct but it's an ordinary one and, therefore, doesn't attract a curious learner's mind.

Btw, I mistook the question as being "Why such bizarre inversion in the first place?" I don't have a good answer, but in many such cases it's because some familiar quotation from old or poetic usages is being altered to the situation. Like maybe, to a new parent, "Send not to know for whom the baby cries; it cries for thee," playing on John Donne. But I don't recognize any allusion in this case.

The phrase headed by of is a required complement of consists, as consists cannot stand alone. *The working day consists.  When the complement is fronted, DO becomes the predicate and the lexical verb base form becomes a subject complement....sorta.

(4) is, of course, the natural form of the sentence. The inverted form is a  'fancy' way of emphasising 'such cavils'.

Note the comma isn't needed in #3. #3 reminds me of the line from The Tempest "Of his bones are corals made."

@KateBunting The first sentence of your comment is no linked with the questions of the original post. The second sentence is written very unclearly. If it's supposed to answer the question "What's the difference between (1), (2) and (3)?", then I can only guess what you mean: maybe you compare (1) with (3), maybe (2) with (3), maybe (1)&(2) with (3). Such uncertainty makes the second sentence useless. So both sentences of your comment don't clarify any of the questions asked. That is, the whole comment is unhelpful.

I was simply pointing out that what you call 'your variant' No. 4 is just the normal way to say this. (1), (2) and (3) are all 'inverted' in the sense that they put Of countless such cavils at the beginning instead of in its natural place at the end - in order to emphasise it. Oh, and (1) is the most idiomatic way to do this.
